# Determine if `UIView` is loaded from XIB or instantiated from code

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I use the following code to force a subclass of `UIView` to load from a XIB file whose name is the actual class name:

```
class NibView : UIView {
    override func awakeAfter(using aDecoder: NSCoder) -> Any? {
        guard isRawView() else { return self }
        for view in self.subviews {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let view = instanceFromNib()
        return view
    }

    func isRawView() -> Bool {
        // What here?
    }
}
```

The purpose of the `isRawView()` method is to determine whether this view has been created from code, or it's been loaded from the corresponding XIB file.
The implementation I've used so far is:

```
func isRawView() -> Bool {
    // A subview created by code (as opposed to  being deserialized from a nib)
    // has 2 subviews, both implementing the `UILayerSupport` protocol
    return
        self.subviews.count == 2 &&
        self.subviews.flatMap(
            { $0.conforms(to: UILayoutSupport.self) ? $0 : nil }).count == 2
}
```

which uses a trick to determine if the view is created from code, because in such cases it contains exactly 2 subviews, both implementing the `UILayoutSupport` protocol.

This works nicely when a `NibView` subclass is instantiated from code. However **it doesn't work if the view is created as part of a view controller in a storyboard** (and presumably the same happens for view controllers and views loaded from XIB files).

Long story to explain the reason of my question: **is there a way for a `UIView` to know whether it's been loaded from a XIB file, and possibly the name of that file?** Or, otherwise, an alternative way of implementing the `isRawView()` method, which should:

- return `false` if the view has been deserialized from an associated XIB file (whose name is the class name)
- return `true` otherwise

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the provided `init` functions.

- [`init(frame:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622488-init) -> From code
- [`init(coder:​)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoding/1416145-init) -> From nib

Example code:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    print("From code")
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    print("From nib")
}
```

I can print out the class name like this:

```
print(NSStringFromClass(type(of: self)).components(separatedBy: ".").last ?? "Couldn't get it")
```

You should be able to use that, maybe with some  slight adjustments, to get what you need.

Comment: That can help me differentiate between code and xib, but I think it doesn't tell me which xib has been used.

Comment: @Antonio; I updated my answer with some code that can print the class name.

Comment: it's the xib file name and not the class name I am looking for. `super.init(coder: aDecoder)` internally invokes `awakeAfter(using:)`, and in that method I need to determine whether the current view has been loaded from the xib file whose name is the class name.

Comment: Doesn't your xib have a custom class "linked" to it? In that you could have a property i.e `nibName` that you set in code and then you can check `view.nibName`?

Comment: I could, but still I need to determine when I can set it. If `awakeAfter(using:)` doesn't return `self`, it means it creates and returns a new view. In order to set that property, I would need to do it before `awakeAfter(using:)` is invoked on the new instance, but that is automatically called by the `init?(coder:)` initializer, and that happens to be too late.